# Get tasks and services running for a user

Tags: windows-services, autoit, windows-server, windows-task-scheduler

My AutoIt script changes password of UserA on multiple Windows Servers using pspasswd from ps-tools.

After changing password I want to check for all tasks and services that run under UserA's context and change those passwords as well. I thought about sc and schtasks but I'm not sure how to get services and tasks from UserA only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <array.au3>; Only for _ArrayDisplay()

$avProcProps = _ProcessListProperties()
_ArrayDisplay($avProcProps, "$avProcProps")

;===============================================================================
; Function Name:    _ProcessListProperties()
; Description:   Get various properties of a process, or all processes
; Call With:       _ProcessListProperties( [$Process [, $sComputer]] )
; Parameter(s):     (optional) $Process - PID or name of a process, default is all
;           (optional) $sComputer - remote computer to get list from, default is local
; Requirement(s):   AutoIt v3.2.4.9+
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns a 2D array of processes, as in ProcessList()
;             with additional columns added:
;             [0][0] - Number of processes listed (can be 0 if no matches found)
;             [1][0] - 1st process name
;             [1][1] - 1st process PID
;             [1][2] - 1st process Parent PID
;             [1][3] - 1st process owner
;             [1][4] - 1st process priority (0 = low, 31 = high)
;             [1][5] - 1st process executable path
;             [1][6] - 1st process CPU usage
;             [1][7] - 1st process memory usage
;             [1][8] - 1st process creation date/time = "MM/DD/YYY hh:mm:ss" (hh = 00 to 23)
;             ...
;             [n][0] thru [n][8] - last process properties
; On Failure:       Returns array with [0][0] = 0 and sets @Error to non-zero (see code below)
; Author(s):        PsaltyDS at http://www.autoitscript.com/forum
; Date/Version:   05/05/2008  --  v1.0.0
; Notes:            If a numeric PID or string process name is provided and no match is found,
;             then [0][0] = 0 and @error = 0 (not treated as an error, same as ProcessList)
;           This function requires admin permissions to the target computer.
;           All properties come from the Win32_Process class in WMI.
;===============================================================================
Func _ProcessListProperties($Process = "", $sComputer = ".")
    Local $sUserName, $sMsg, $sUserDomain, $avProcs
    If $Process = "" Then
        $avProcs = ProcessList()
    Else
        $avProcs = ProcessList($Process)
    EndIf

   ; Return for no matches
    If $avProcs[0][0] = 0 Then Return $avProcs

   ; ReDim array for additional property columns
    ReDim $avProcs[$avProcs[0][0] + 1][9]

   ; Connect to WMI and get process objects
    $oWMI = ObjGet("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & $sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    If IsObj($oWMI) Then
       ; Get collection of all processes from Win32_Process
        $colProcs = $oWMI.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process")
        If IsObj($colProcs) Then
           ; For each process...
            For $oProc In $colProcs
                $sObjName = ObjName($oProc, 1)
                If @error Then ContinueLoop; Skip if process no longer exists
               ; Find it in the array
                For $n = 1 To $avProcs[0][0]
                    If $avProcs[$n][1] = $oProc.ProcessId Then

                       ; [n][2] = Parent PID
                        $avProcs[$n][2] = $oProc.ParentProcessId
                       ; [n][3] = Owner
                        If $oProc.GetOwner($sUserName, $sUserDomain) = 0 Then $avProcs[$n][3] = $sUserDomain & "\" & $sUserName
                       ; [n][4] = Priority
                        $avProcs[$n][4] = $oProc.Priority
                       ; [n][5] = Executable path
                        $avProcs[$n][5] = $oProc.ExecutablePath
                       ; [n][8] = Creation date/time
                        Local $dtmDate = $oProc.CreationDate
                        If $dtmDate <> "" Then
                            $dtmDate = StringMid($dtmDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
                                    StringMid($dtmDate, 7, 2) & "/" & _
                                    StringLeft($dtmDate, 4) & " " & _
                                    StringMid($dtmDate, 9, 2) & ":" & _
                                    StringMid($dtmDate, 11, 2) & ":" & _
                                    StringMid($dtmDate, 13, 2)
                        EndIf
                        $avProcs[$n][8] = $dtmDate

                        ExitLoop
                    EndIf
                Next
            Next
        Else
            SetError(2); Error getting process collection from WMI
        EndIf

       ; Get collection of all processes from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
       ; Have to use an SWbemRefresher to pull the collection, or all Perf data will be zeros
        Local $oRefresher = ObjCreate("WbemScripting.SWbemRefresher")
        $colProcs = $oRefresher.AddEnum($oWMI, "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process" ).objectSet
        $oRefresher.Refresh

       ; Time delay before calling refresher
        Local $iTime = TimerInit()
        Do
            Sleep(10)
        Until TimerDiff($iTime) > 100
        $oRefresher.Refresh

       ; Get PerfProc data
        For $oProc In $colProcs
           ; Find it in the array
            For $n = 1 To $avProcs[0][0]
                If $avProcs[$n][1] = $oProc.IDProcess Then
                   ; [n][6] = CPU usage
                    $avProcs[$n][6] = $oProc.PercentProcessorTime
                   ; [n][7] = memory usage
                    $avProcs[$n][7] = $oProc.WorkingSet
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            Next
        Next
    Else
        SetError(1); Error connecting to WMI
    EndIf

   ; Return array
    Return $avProcs
EndFunc  ;==>_ProcessListProperties


Global $aServicesInfo
_ComputerGetServices($aServicesInfo, "All")
_ArrayDisplay($aServicesInfo)

;===============================================================================
; Description:      Returns the services information in an array.
; Parameter(s):     $aServicesInfo - By Reference - Services Information array.
;                   $sState - OPTIONAL - Accepted values 'All' or 'Stopped' or
;                                       'Running'
; Requirement(s):   None
; Return Value(s):  On Success - Returns array of Services Information.
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][0]  = Name
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][1]  = Accept Pause
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][2]  = Accept Stop
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][3]  = Check Point
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][4]  = Description
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][5]  = Creation Class Name
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][6]  = Desktop Interact
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][7]  = Display Name
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][8]  = Error Control
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][9]  = Exit Code
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][10] = Path Name
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][11] = Process ID
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][12] = Service Specific Exit Code
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][13] = Service Type
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][14] = Started
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][15] = Start Mode
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][16] = Start Name
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][17] = State
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][18] = Status
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][19] = System Creation Class Name
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][20] = System Name
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][21] = Tag ID
;                       $aServicesInfo[$i][22] = Wait Hint
;
;                   On Failure - @error = 1 and Returns 0
;                               @extended = 1 - Array contains no information
;                                           2 - $colItems isnt an object
; Author(s):        Jarvis Stubblefield (support "at" vortexrevolutions "dot" com)
; Note(s):
;===============================================================================
Func _ComputerGetServices(ByRef $aServicesInfo, $sState = "All")
    Local $cI_Compname = @ComputerName, $wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 0x10, $wbemFlagForwardOnly = 0x20
    Local $colItems, $objWMIService, $objItem
    Dim $aServicesInfo[1][23], $i = 1

    $objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\" & $cI_Compname & "\root\CIMV2")
    $colItems = $objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service", "WQL", $wbemFlagReturnImmediately + $wbemFlagForwardOnly)

    If IsObj($colItems) Then
        For $objItem In $colItems
            If $sState <> "All" Then
                If $sState = "Stopped" And $objItem.State <> "Stopped" Then ContinueLoop
                If $sState = "Running" And $objItem.State <> "Running" Then ContinueLoop
            EndIf
            ReDim $aServicesInfo[UBound($aServicesInfo) + 1][23]
            $aServicesInfo[$i][0] = $objItem.Name
            $aServicesInfo[$i][1] = $objItem.AcceptPause
            $aServicesInfo[$i][2] = $objItem.AcceptStop
            $aServicesInfo[$i][3] = $objItem.CheckPoint
            $aServicesInfo[$i][4] = $objItem.Description
            $aServicesInfo[$i][5] = $objItem.CreationClassName
            $aServicesInfo[$i][6] = $objItem.DesktopInteract
            $aServicesInfo[$i][7] = $objItem.DisplayName
            $aServicesInfo[$i][8] = $objItem.ErrorControl
            $aServicesInfo[$i][9] = $objItem.ExitCode
            $aServicesInfo[$i][10] = $objItem.PathName
            $aServicesInfo[$i][11] = $objItem.ProcessId
            $aServicesInfo[$i][12] = $objItem.ServiceSpecificExitCode
            $aServicesInfo[$i][13] = $objItem.ServiceType
            $aServicesInfo[$i][14] = $objItem.Started
            $aServicesInfo[$i][15] = $objItem.StartMode
            $aServicesInfo[$i][16] = $objItem.StartName
            $aServicesInfo[$i][17] = $objItem.State
            $aServicesInfo[$i][18] = $objItem.Status
            $aServicesInfo[$i][19] = $objItem.SystemCreationClassName
            $aServicesInfo[$i][20] = $objItem.SystemName
            $aServicesInfo[$i][21] = $objItem.TagId
            $aServicesInfo[$i][22] = $objItem.WaitHint
            $i += 1
        Next
        $aServicesInfo[0][0] = UBound($aServicesInfo) - 1
        If $aServicesInfo[0][0] < 1 Then
            SetError(1, 1, 0)
        EndIf
    Else
        SetError(1, 2, 0)
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_ComputerGetServices
```